# Android Studio/ Firebase Data Notification send with default parameters

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification

I'm currently making an app on android studio and I am getting stuck.
 
I've mananaged to have my notifications displayed when the app is open or closed, and when the app is in foreground, I receive the notification with the modifications I made on the MyFirebaseInstanceIdService file (see the file below), but i can't manage to display the notification when the app is closed or in background (meaning when it's a data notification) with the modifications I made (like the change of icon for the notification).

here is the code of the MyFirebaseInstanceIdService, the file managing my notifications

```
package com.shayru.myapplication.Service;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;
import com.shayru.myapplication.R;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;

public class MyFirebaseInstanceIdService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    //Ctrl o
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

        if(remoteMessage.getData().isEmpty())
            showNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(),remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        else
            showNotification(remoteMessage.getData());

    }


    private void showNotification(Map<String,String> data) {
        String title = data.get("title").toString();
        String body = data.get("body").toString();

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID ="com.shayru.myapplication.test";

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        {
            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID,"Notification",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);

            notificationChannel.setDescription("CE Valeo");
            notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
            notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
            notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{0,1000,500,1000});
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);

        }

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);

        notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                //R to take from "com.Shayru.myapp
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(body)
                .setContentInfo("Info");


        notificationManager.notify(new Random().nextInt(),notificationBuilder.build());
    }

    private void showNotification(String title, String body) {
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID ="com.shayru.myapplication.test";

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        {
            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID,"Notification",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);

            notificationChannel.setDescription("CE Valeo");
            notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
            notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
            notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{0,1000,500,1000});
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);

        }

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);

        notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                //R to take from "com.Shayru.myapp
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(body)
                .setContentInfo("Info");


        notificationManager.notify(new Random().nextInt(),notificationBuilder.build());
    }

}
```

Comment: As reference of firebase notification .. when app is not open (even in back ground ) android will show  notification with default settings

Comment: Well there must be a way to do it a lot of android apps do it

Comment: you have any server as backend in your app??

Comment: I do own a server but I don't know how to do that